# Ajax Call Not Returning Data Django

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django

I want to write a simple `ajax` method to fire up whenever the `document` is ready. I have the following `JS`:

```
$(document).ready(function()
    {
    $.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        url: '/get_alert',
        sucess: function(data){
            data = JSON.parse(data);
            alert("Hi");
            console.log(data);
            $('#notification_symbol').css('display','inline');
        },
        error: function(){
            console.log("Hello");
        }
    });
 }
```

I can confirm that the url is working and that the call is being made on `ready`. However, it is not returning any data. Here is my function in `views.py`:

```
def get_alert(request):
    alert = False
    events = EventInvite.objects.filter(Invitee_id=request.user.id, Status= InvitationStatus.objects.filter(Status='Pending')[0]).order_by('-date')
    for event in events:
        if event.seen:
            alert = True
    dict = {
        'alert':alert,
    }
    print(dict) # Tells me the call is being made on ready...
    return JsonResponse(dict)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> sucess: function(data){
> ```

Noticed that `success` is misspelled.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have CSRF token code in place? This is usually the issue for me when having ajax-y problems. I'm not sure what django you're working with (I'm around ~1.8) but the following code usually clears this up for me. Just plop this in a script tag in your html page. This auto posts CSRF stuff when you do ajax calls.

```
function getCookie(name) {
var cookieValue = null;
if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
     var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
        var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
        // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
        if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
            cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
            break;
        }
    }
}
return cookieValue;
}


var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
   function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
   // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
  return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
}


$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
        if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
      }
  }
});
```

[This link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/csrf/) contains the django docs reference pages that explain these snippets.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I misspelled `success` :(

Comment: D'oh! I should have realized that this wasn't the case when you said your function was being properly called. Maybe we're both short on coffee this morning ;)